# Autoposting to Facebook for database of users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on application (in Ruby on Rails) which should be able to post automatically to Facebook (like http://postcron.com/).
I suposse I need to get access token for every user in application. When I have an access token, I should be able to post on Facebook of this user on given time using cron or something like this. Am I right?

Which gem should I use? I have found omniauth-facebook and koala.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Once the user grants access to your Facebook app, you simple store their token and use it when you want to post through their FB profile.

You do, however, need to consider the fact that the token WILL expire (I believe it is after 2 hours).

Comment: But how it is done in apps where I can plan posting for few days or months?

Comment: @kmaci

You can extend the user token for up to 2 months.